# Using execl to call file from folder

Tags: c

I'm writing a program in C in Linux which creates main and assistant process and communication should be like: Main process (parent) receives keyboard input (char array) then passes it through pipe to assistant (child) process, then child should call some other .c file with `execl` (my .c file to call is named simple.c) and then pass the result on the second pipe... and at that point with `execl` I have some issue, here is my child code:

```
if (childpid == 0) {
    printf("I am child!\n");
    if (dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1
        || dup2(fd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1)
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Child error: Redirection of std input/output failed!");
    else if (close(fd[0]) == -1 || close(fd[1]) == -1
         || close(fd2[0]) == -1 || close(fd2[1]) == -1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Child error: Pipes closing failed!");
    else {
        execl("/home/myproj/simple.c", " ", NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, " Execl failed ! ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

simple.c should be something like this:

```
int main()
{
    // ...
    read(0, string, sizeof(string));
    string[0] = string[1];
    write(1, string, sizeof(string)); // sending new string on second pipe
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help me whats the problem with `execl` line? Thanks a lot.

Comment: [`excecl` will not return](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) if there is no error. You need to `fork` the process.

Comment: Also, unless you just have a very odd naming convention, you can't `execl` a `something.c` file - you need to compile your C code into executable files, which can then be run in the usual ways...

Comment: Oh, ofc its should be executable to call it with exec. I missed that one, thanks a lot mates!

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody help me whats the problem with execl line?

You could have helped yourself by not using the poor error message

```
        fprintf(stderr, " Execl failed ! ");
```

but something more sensible, like

```
        perror("execl /home/myproj/simple.c");
```

this would have told you *Permission denied* and you could have looked up the possible reasons in the manual, finding the most probable:

> The file described by path or file is not
>                                  executable.